# unresolved import 'chromedriver_install' Python(unresolved-import)

Tags: import, python3

```
py -m pip install chromedriver_install
Requirement already satisfied: chromedriver_install in c:\users\bckelley\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (1.0.3)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Using Ubuntu Linux here... so adapt for Windows or whatever you have*<

If you have one package version already installed, and need to replace it with e.g. a newer version - then these things might give a you hint of how one might go about it...

```
$ python3 -m pip

Usage:   
  /usr/bin/python3 -m pip  [options]

Commands:
  install                     Install packages.
  download                    Download packages.
  uninstall                   Uninstall packages.
  freeze                      Output installed packages in requirements format.
  list                        List installed packages.
  show                        Show information about installed packages.
  search                      Search PyPI for packages.
  wheel                       Build wheels from your requirements.
  hash                        Compute hashes of package archives.
  completion                  A helper command used for command completion
  help                        Show help for commands.

General Options:
  -h, --help                  Show help.
  --isolated                  Run pip in an isolated mode, ignoring environment variables and user configuration.
  -v, --verbose               Give more output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times.
  -V, --version               Show version and exit.
  -q, --quiet                 Give less output.
  --log                 Path to a verbose appending log.
  --proxy              Specify a proxy in the form [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port.
  --retries          Maximum number of retries each connection should attempt (default 5 times).
  --timeout              Set the socket timeout (default 15 seconds).
  --exists-action     Default action when a path already exists: (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup.
  --trusted-host    Mark this host as trusted, even though it does not have valid or any HTTPS.
  --cert                Path to alternate CA bundle.
  --client-cert         Path to SSL client certificate, a single file containing the private key and the certificate in PEM format.
  --cache-dir            Store the cache data in .
  --no-cache-dir              Disable the cache.
  --disable-pip-version-check
                              Don't periodically check PyPI to determine whether a new version of pip is available for download. Implied with --no-index.
```

In there you see "list" as a command, so

> $ python3 -m pip list

would show a list of installed packages.
another option is to remove an installed package; e.g.

> $ python3 -m pip uninstall package_name

and finally

> $ python3 -m pip install package_name

Now, please note that there may exist intricate dependencies between packages, and as I currently cannot provide proper advice regarding this; my fallback is: Make sure to take a backup of your system before you attempt any changes.
That way you have the option to restore what you changed.

Also note that

> $ python3 -m pip help freeze

will show options specific to "freeze"; those are options which allow you to save a list of currently installed packages - a list which later can be used together with what is show here:

> $ python3 -m pip help install

to actually install those back again.

... please note though that some things might be hard to reinstall if you remove too much (i.e. "one wrong vital package").

---

**NOTES FOR Ubuntu 20.04**

There is no Python2. Use:

> $ python3 ...

"pip" isn't installed by default, do:

> $ sudo apt install python3-pip

... to get it installed. (That will though CURRENTLY pull in a load of packages, including 'build-essential')

Comment: That doesn't really help, I have it installed. The script isn't finding it or something

Comment: Implied above: The installed version is not the required / expected version. No-one can tell from the low detail in your post though.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. chromedriver_install is version (1.0.3), what is it expecting??

Comment: What you have written in your question does not provide enough detail to answer that question. I haven't got the slightest idea. What I provided was a means to go and investigate basic information that MIGHT give you an idea where the actual problem is.

Comment: I didn't know what to actually put, totally new to python, that was what I did, installed chromedriver_install and then the error that was produced. Please what else can I add to help?

Comment: If I google chromedriver_install I find references to https://pypi.org/project/pyderman/ - I get the impression that is a newer version of what you expect google chromedriver_install to be. You might wish to look into it. I have no idea what this is expected to be and will be deleting the above shortly.

Comment: That was it. Thank You for putting up with me!